# Render reactjs component in multiple div tags

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a React.JS component which can be rendered in multiple places using the *classname* of `div` elements instead of an *id*.

The regular way to render a component is this:

```
React.render(<Component/>, document.getElementById('id'))
```

while I wonder if it' possible to do this:

```
React.render(<Component/>, document.getElementsByClassName)?
```

Answer (score 7):

`React.render` takes a single DOM element. If you want to render it more than once, simply iterate over the nodes.

```
function renderToElements(toRender, elements) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    React.render(toRender, elements[i]);
  }
}

renderToElements(..., document.getElementsByClassName("className"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding onto @Michelle Tilley's answer, I really wanted to do this technique while grabbing a dataset from each element to pass in as a prop. The key was to pass the **ComponentName** without quotes or brackets and then to createElement with it :

```
let elems = document.getElementsByClassName("class_name");

function renderToElements(toRender, elements, dataset) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let passId = elements[i].dataset[dataset];
    let renderEl = React.createElement(toRender, {id: passId})
    ReactDOM.render(renderEl, elements[i]);
  }
}

renderToElements(ComponentName, elems, 'id')
```